# problem: How to check variable same or not?

Tags: java, flutter, dart

Here I have two variable with same item but when i checking it then it is saying its not same.

Here I want variable a and variable b both same after chacking and I want variable c and variable d both not same after chacking.

```
void main() {
  var a = 'Onion,Pepper,Paneer';
  var b = 'Pepper,Paneer,Onion';
  if (a.contains(b)) {
    print('This is same');
  } else {
    print('This is not same.');
  }

var c = 'Onion,Pepper,Paneer';
  var d = 'Pepper,Onion'; Or 'Onion,Pepper,Cheese';
  if (c.contains(d)) {
    print('This is same');
  } else {
    print('This is not same.');
  }

}
```

Comment: Try using `String::split`

Comment: by what logic do you think this contains should return true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variables *are not* the same.

What you probably want to do is take these two sentences, split them into words at the comma and compare whether your lists of words contain the same words (probably without any priority on the order, Pepper and Salt is the same as Salt and Pepper).

Since you tagged it [dart](/questions/tagged/dart):

```
void main() {
  var a = 'Onion,Pepper,Paneer'.split(',');
  var b = 'Pepper,Paneer,Onion'.split(',');
  
  if (a.containsTheSameElementsAs(b)) {
    print('This is same');
  } else {
    print('This is not same.');
  }

  var c = 'Onion,Pepper,Paneer'.split(',');
  var d = 'Pepper,Onion'.split(','); 
  if (c.containsTheSameElementsAs(d)) {
    print('This is same');
  } else {
    print('This is not same.');
  }
}

extension on List {
  bool containsTheSameElementsAs(List other) {
    return length == other.length && every(other.contains);
  }
}
```

I'm sure something very similar is available in [java](/questions/tagged/java).